# Web scraping looping through letters and numbers in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some data from a website which have an address that consists of both letters and numbers. The below code works, but is not the ideal solution. While I know up front that I need to loop through the letters A-Z, the actual number in the web address is different depending on whether it is A,B,C, etc...However, none of the letters go further than 100.

Thus sometime I have the address,
web_letters_A_web_numbers_1-web_letters_A_web_numbers_76
Other times,
web_letters_B_web_numbers_1-web_letters_B_web_numbers_100

When my loop hits *_77 for letter A above the page displays what was in *_76, so I am good to go, except that I get these observations read twice, but I can actually fix this deleting duplicates in a final step. However, I would like the script to move on to the letter B, once it finds those duplicates observations. Any suggestions?

```
require(plyr)
require(XML)
dat <- data.frame()

for (A in letters){  
    for(i in 1:100) { 
      dat.pre <- readHTMLTable((paste("web_letters_",A,"_web_numbers_", i, sep = '')),   which=1)
    n <- max(length(dat), length(dat.pre))
    length(dat) <- n
    length(dat.pre) <- n
    dat <- rbind(dat, dat.pre)  
  }
}
```

Comment: The right way is probably to get the list of actual urls rather than loop over the alphabet and hope for the best. But you don't give us the website so it's hard to say.

Comment: Maybe, but in the end these pages may end up being 40 000 pages, and the number of pages will occassionaly change within the letters. Thus, obtaining a list might be difficult.

Comment: It might be difficult, but we can't know because you still haven't shown us what you are actually working with. All we have is pseudo-code, which is likely why there is no answer to this question yet.